# Hadoop MapReduce 1.0.2 eclipse-plugin build fails...I don't get it

Tags: eclipse-plugin, hadoop, mapreduce

I have tried to build the Hadoop MapReduce eclipse-plugin from source, but get the following error.

```
SRC_BASE_DIR/hadoop-common/hadoop-mapreduce-project/build/ivy/lib/Hadoop/common
does not exist.
```

I cloned the Hadoop source from the Apache GIT repo and managed to build the actual Hadoop binaries using the following commands

```
cd SRC_BASE_DIR/hadoop-common
mvn clean install
```

This was successful so next I changed directory

```
cd SRC_BASE_DIR/hadoop-common/hadoop-mapreduce-project/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin
```

I appended eclipse.home property to the build.properties file...

```
echo "eclipse.home=/opt/eclipse" >> build.properties
```

then tried to build the plugin...

```
ant jar
```

But I still get the error outlined above.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

OK I was missing a step.

In the folder

```
SRC_BASE_DIR/hadoop-common/hadoop-mapreduce-project
```

I ran the following command

```
mvn -DskipTests install
```

which was successful. Then in folder

```
SRC_BASE_DIR/hadoop-common/hadoop-mapreduce-project/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin
```

I ran the command

```
ant jar
```

and this time it was succesful and created the JAR file **hadoop-1.0.2-eclipse-plugin.jar**

Now, I just hope that that the plugin works!

Comment: did it work? I my case the plugin built with no version. That is instead of 1.0.2 I had ${version} and it reported no errors. And the plugin did not work